# Using NDSolve solution as initial condition for another NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have solved a PDE numerically using `NDSolve`, and I now need to be able to use that solution as an initial condition for another `NDSolve`. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I really think so.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What exactly is the issue you find?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[t]==..., y[0]==...},y,{t,0,10}];

sol2 = NDSolve[{y'[t]==..., y[0]==(y[10]/.sol1)},y,{t,10,20}];
```